# Creating a map book for feature elements

Tags: report

I have a point feature class that is survey monuments.  I'd like to create a page for each survey monument that would have a a overview map showing where the monument is and a report on the attributes.  Ideally I'd like to be able to insert photos that are attached to the feature.

I'm trying to determine what software would be best to do this, and any tricks I need to know.  I have access to the following software:

- ArcMap
- ArcGIS Pro
- FME
- Geocortex

It seems like this should be a common type of thing to want to do, but I can't seem to figure out how to do it in any software other than using the Geocortex reporting tool.  However, these aren't currently in our Geocortex site and it is quite cumbersome to get everything to a point where I can create reports there.

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out.  Not sure why I missed it initially.  In ArcGIS Pro they are called Map Series and in ArcMap they are data driven maps.

Searching on those will give tonnes of information on how to do them.